# Google Analytics custom variables, data fed via URL

Tags: google-analytics

I've been asked to set-up some custom variables but as I'm new to it, have no idea on how to get started. I have researched as much as I can but am getting confused.

Here's what I need to do:
An app generates a unique URL in the form http://www.example.com/folder/?userID=12345&BookTitle=ABCDE&DateAndTime=201208080800. I then need the custom variables from the URL ('UserID', 
'BookTitle' and 'DateAndTime') to be passed to Google Analytics so I can track which users of the app are visiting the page at that URL.

I've looked into setting up custom variables but don't understand if I need 3 separate lines of code for the 3 separate variables nor how I can pass the various elements of the URL through to these.

Can anyone shed any light on how I might go about doing this?

Many thanks for any help in advance.
-Jack

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. It turns out this kind of usage is against Google Analytics' TOS.
Going about it a different way by asking the user for some info up-front instead.

Answer (score 0):

Google's ToS has changed. You can do this now as long as the UserID is internal to you and cannot be used to identify the customer (by Google).